# How can I automatically centre new windows in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, automation

Is there a setting or third-party app for Yosemite which will make all new windows open in the center of my display? For instance, when I open a new Finder window, or launch an app.

I've found a wonderful app called [Spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com/) which lets me center windows (and do all kinds of other useful things) using keyboard shortcuts, but I'd like to automate centering if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Can it be scripted using AppleScript ?
Any time your open a new App, it could call a script to center the Windows.
I do not know if this is possible with your tool, but it is with this one:
http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/